# change numerical vectors to 1 if > 0 or 0 in r

Tags: r, binary, dplyr

lesion2 <- mutate_each(lesion, list(~as.binary(.,logic = TRUE)), -dim)
with lesion as data frame and dim as variable not converted to binary form of TRUE| FALSE

[image]

Comment: can you share any sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `replace` in base R.

```
v
# [1]  0 -1  1  1 -1  2  1  2  1 -1 -1  0

v <- replace(v, v >= 0, 1)
v
# [1] -2  1 -2 -2 -1  1 -1 -1 -2  1 -2  1
```

To apply this on multiple columns of a data frame, use it in an `lapply`.

```
d
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1   a -1 -2
# 2   b -2  2
# 3   c  0 -2
# 4   d -1  1
# 5   e -2  1
# 6   f  2  2
# 7   g  0 -2
# 8   h  2  0
# 9   i  0  2
# 10  j  0  1
# 11  k  2  0
# 12  l  1  2

d[c("V2", "V3")] <- lapply(d[c("V2", "V3")], function(v) replace(v, v >= 0, 1))
d
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1   a -1 -2
# 2   b -2  1
# 3   c  1 -2
# 4   d -1  1
# 5   e -2  1
# 6   f  1  1
# 7   g  1 -2
# 8   h  1  1
# 9   i  1  1
# 10  j  1  1
# 11  k  1  1
# 12  l  1  1
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 12
v <- sample(-2:2, n, replace=TRUE)

d <- data.frame(V1=letters[1:n],
                V2=sample(-2:2, n, replace=TRUE),
                V3=sample(-2:2, n, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this to a data frame, so each variable is not done individually?